# Is it possible to concatenate list indices in one statement in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list that looks like

```
alist = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

and I want to pass it to a function that looks like

```
def callme(a, b, e):
    pass
```

So, I would like to do something like

```
callme(*alist[0,1,4])
```

Is there a one liner that will achieve this?

EDIT

I could also do this, I guess (**EDIT** Don't do it this way, drewk has answered with a better method of enumeration.)

```
callme(*[a for a in alist if alist.index(a) in [0,1,4]])
```

Comment: `callme(alist[0], alist[1], alist[4])` is still a one-liner and a lot more obvious.  Is your objection to this the fact that you must write `alist` three times, so that, e.g., this would not work for `callme(f()[0], f()[1], f()[4])` where function `f` has side effects?

Comment: @torek My reasoning is a bit convoluted but the gist is: I have to make a call to this function from multiple places, but the list in each place is stored differently - so it would be nice if I could just edit the indices. EDIT: Yes, also the fact that the lists might have different names in each location.

Comment: Ah, it makes much more sense that way.

Comment: @torek Your way is more responsive, though, if I want to substitute in an argument that doesn't come from the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
callme(*itemgetter(0, 1, 4)(alist))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
>>> alist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> [a for i,a in enumerate(alist) if i in (0,1,4)]
['a', 'b', 'e']
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could enumerate like that.

Comment: Note that this works better than the `alist.index` method in the question, as it behaves properly for duplicate values, e.g., `alist=[0,1,2,3,3]; [a for a in alist if alist.index(a) in [0,1,4]]` only outputs `[0,1]`.